# Get filename from url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, file-io

I am using file picker. File picker gives me a url like this after saving the file `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/YVlnXammQium3ukD3Zf4`

But how do I know what the file name is? When I enter this URL in my browser I get the download tab and the tab shows me the `filename`. How can I get the file name using `javascript`?

Is there another way to get the file name? I am using `Rails` as a backend and `Backbone` as the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the filename via `metadata`:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/metadata?filename=true
```

In `Javascript` this would look like:

```
var blob = { url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG' };

console.log("Loading metadata...");
filepicker.stat(
  blob,
  {
    filename: true
  },
  function(metadata){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata));
  }
);
```

[**All of this is in the documentation**](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/javascript_api/), so take a look there for more info.